# Elegant way to remove a ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

I am looking for an *elegant* way to remove a specific menu item called `Annotate` from the `ContextMenu`. This is how it is done, so I would appreciate your input on this.

```
public sealed class ContextMenuStripEx : ContextMenuStrip
{
    private readonly ToolStripMenuItem _createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    ...

    public PlotContextMenuStripEx()
    {
        ...
        Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[]
                               {
                                   ...
                                   _createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem,
                                   ...
                               });
        // 
        // createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        _createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem.Name = "createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem";
        _createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem.Size = new Size(169, 22);
        _createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem.Image = CommonRes.tsAnnotateM;
        _createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Annotate";
   }
}
```

Now imagine somewhere else in another class there is a call to get the ContextMenuStrip, something like:

```
ContextMenuStrip menuplot = myControl.GetPaneContextMenu();
```

I want to make the removal part more elegant, because I dont want to rely on the string comparison. Its very ugly:

```
foreach (var item in menuplot.Items)
{
    var name = (item as ToolStripItem).Name;
    if (string.Compare(name, "createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem") == 0)
    {
        // remove the item 
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this please? many thanks.

Comment: You already have a _createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem variable to keep the reference, why are you trying to find it back when you already have it?

Comment: because the context menu changes based on the business domain logic. The context menu is altered from different places within several projects that use the UI control. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

- having the menu items references property accessors set to internal, or public.
- On the other hand, I would *hide* menu items instead of *removing* them. This can be done in the [`Opening`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening(v=vs.110).aspx) event. The reason is that removing items from the collection may be painful to handle later when the same instance of the context menu is reused.

Instead of a loop and removal, I use this way:

```
void menuplot_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // Accessible menu items are easier to handle
    menuplot.createAnnotationToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;
    ...
}
```

The Opening event is interesting. For example, it allows you to check and cancel the opening of the popup if your conditions are not met by setting `e.Cancel = true;`